# convert back to class type List from GenericEntity - anonymous class

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am getting class cast exception at line 7 in the code below. I have written line 1-3 to provide data that comes from a rest service call and these line can't be changed from my side. I must cast the response to List

```
    List<Integer> lstInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lstInt.add(1);
    lstInt.add(2);

    GenericEntity<List<Integer>> gEntity = new GenericEntity<List<Integer>>(lstInt) {};
    System.out.println(gEntity.getClass()); //prints com.org.dept.proj.MyClass$12
    List<Integer> output = (List<Integer>) gEntity; // class cast exception
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Well obviously. `gEntity` is a `GenericEntity`. It is not a List. It simply *contains* one.

Comment: `Object foo = "foo"; Integer bar = (Integer) foo;` [This results in a class cast exception](https://ideone.com/3ZgHD5) for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @Michael - Is there a way to get the `List` then?

Comment: @Michael - there is no class cast exception for the case of `foo` example `Object foo = new Integer(1);
  Integer intVar = (Integer) foo;`

Comment: That's because an integer is an integer. I chose my example very specifically. By changing it you have undermined the entire point. Again, a GenericEntity is not a List.

Comment: @Michael - Got you! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Michael. I had to run a `getEntity` on `gEntity` and then cast it as per the documentation

```
        List<Integer> lstInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lstInt.add(1);
        lstInt.add(2);
        GenericEntity<List<Integer>> gEntity = new GenericEntity<List<Integer>>(lstInt) {};
        System.out.println(gEntity.getEntity());
        List<Integer> output = (List<Integer>) gEntity.getEntity();
        System.out.println(output);
```